# How to tell whether a prop has been explicitly passed in to a component in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

Is there any way to tell, from within a Vue 3 component, what props are being **explicitly passed in** (i.e., as attributes on the component's tag in the parent template)—as opposed to being unset and receiving their value from a default?

In other words, if I have a prop declared with a default value, like this:

```js
props: {
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Friend'
  }
}
```

How can I tell the difference between this:

```html
<Greeting name="Friend" />
```

and this:

```html
<Greeting />   <!-- name defaults to 'Friend' -->
```

In both instances, the component's `name` prop will have the same value, in the first case being passed in explicitly and in the second case being assigned the default.

**Is there a systematic way in Vue 3 to determine the difference?**

In Vue 2 you could use `this.$options.propsData` for this purpose—it contained only the properties that were directly passed in. However, it has been [removed in Vue 3](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/props-data.html).

Comment: I think they want you to use `Symbol()` as the default and then check against that value in your `setup()` function. Example here https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#setup

Comment: The only way to do this; the I way I see it is to set the default prop value to `null`. Then from within the `setup` function check if the value is `null` (which means) not explicitly set. But if you want to explicitly set `null` this wont work. If you elaborate on the reason why you need this, maybe we can think of a better way.

Answer (score 1):

This information may be available in component instance with `getCurrentInstance` low level API, but there is no documented way to distinguish default and specified prop value that are `===` equal.

If default prop value is supposed to differ from the same value that was specified explicitly, this means that this isn't the case for default prop value, and it should be specified in some other way, e.g. through a computed:

```
const name = computed(() => {
 if (props.name == null) {
   console.log('default');
   return 'Friend';
 } else
   return props.name;
});
```

Comment: I don't know how people can claim there is "no valid reason" to want to do something. For my use case, I want to display a warning message if the user hasn't specified a value, but also still display the component correctly with a fallback default value.

Comment: @HartleyBrody This indicates XY problem, this is the thing I addressed with "no valid reason" remark. If you need to distinguish raw prop from a prop with fallback value, they need to be initially treated as two different values, this is what a computed is intended for

Comment: This problem becomes apparent when passing a `v-model` to a child component that is either: `ref()`, or, `ref('')`... Both will work just fine for the parent, but in the child, `ref()` will receive it's `default` value, and `ref('')` will stay an empty string, *BUT* on both occasions, the parent component will behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, I believe, although since it's a pretty specialised requirement, we need to directly access Vue's undocumented methods and properties, which is not considered stable (although usually fine).

```
<script setup>
import { getCurrentInstance, computed } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
    test: {
        type: String,
        default: "Hello"
    }
});

const vm = getCurrentInstance();
const propDefaults = vm.propsOptions[0];

const testIsDefault = computed(() => propDefaults.test.default === props.test);
</script>
```